# Deducting an older date from now()

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I have a date `1953-09-02` stored, and I'm trying to get the difference between that and `now()` - I've attempted:

```
select (now() - birth_date) from employees LIMIT 1;
```

However, that's just selecting the date/time for `now()`. (20160202561100)

I attempted to convert `birth_date` from a date type to unix_timestamp using `unix_timestamp(birth_date)` however that's returning 0.

I'm slightly concerned as this is such an old date, and unix standard starting 1970 era, this may not be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DATEDIFF():

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),birth_date) FROM employees LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Awesome, this returned `22818`, this is the difference in days I presume?